# When is an object heavy enough so as to avoid copying?

Tags: c++, memory

Well, I believe the title is pretty straight forward. I've read many times that one should avoid copying heavy objects, and it seems pretty rational (who would want to be a memory hog?). Question is, when should an object be considered heavy? how many members?

Comment: It depends entirely on what the object is and how it is used.

Comment: If you can avoid copying, why not avoid it every time?

Comment: I would say when copying hurts your performance :)

Comment: @James McNellis: and the architecture you're running in.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Define 'hurts'.  This is a reasonable basis for discussion but does not stand up without elaboration imo.

Comment: @Steve: Measurement has shown that, bla bla, bottleneck, and so on.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Because copying simple object (e.g. an `int`) is cheaper than sending and using a reference to it.

Comment: That point is more than a couple of words, according to Bjarne in his C++ Style and Technique FAQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time the object you're passing is larger than the size of a pointer (typically 4 bytes on 32-bit, 8 bytes on 64-bit), then it would be more efficient to avoid copying.

Whether or not you *should* pass it by reference/pointer depends on how much extra work that will be, and what you'll be doing with the data. If you pass it by reference just to create a copy and modify it in your function, then you've defeated the purpose. Any time passing it as const by-reference suffices, then it's probably a good idea to do so.

However, note that most compilers are smart enough to optimize away the copying of a read-only object when your code is compiled with optimizations on. So you needn't really worry about it unless it becomes a bottleneck and you can quantitively prove it.

Comment: I would add that passing a pointer is preferable and sometimes the only way to achieve certain designs ie. pointer to interfaces, pimpls, function pointers etc..

Comment: Passing by reference prevents some optimizations that the compiler may be able to perform on values, so it's not as cut and dry as that.  C++11 seems to have changed the old rules of thumb as well, some are advising passing by value in many places where you'd have previously passed by const reference, particularly for value-like objects such as std::string, due to move semantics.